# Segmentation fault simple pointer double array

Tags: c, pointers

I would like to pass a double array to a function via a pointer. However, despite trying a lot of things suggested here, I always get a segmentation fault upon initialization. I feel that it is very simple code (I am new to C), yet I cannot find my mistake. The code is as follows:

```
double *tMatrix = (double *)malloc(N*sizeof(double));
int i;

for (i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    tMatrix[i] = 0.0;
}

computeMatrix(tMatrix);
```

I get a segmentation fault on the first initialization of tMatrix, that is, when i=0. I want to use a pointer for the array tMatrix as I want to pass the matrix to the function computeMatrix.

Comment: Is `tMatrix == NULL`, perhaps because `N` is very large? You should check such things in your program.

Comment: Also, in C you [should not cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).

Comment: This or `N = 0`

Comment: @MOehm, indeed tMatrix == NULL, however this even holds for small N, say N=10? Ideally, I would like to have N set to 10^9.

Comment: The shown code has no obvious problems which could expalin a segfault (except for above comments). More context is needed. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Size of double is 8 bytes. 8 bytes * 10^9 =~ 7629 MB. Do you have enough RAM?

Comment: A typical `double` has 8 bytes, so you are requesting a _contiguous_ block of about 8GB, which in your case the system cannot provide. Depending on what you want to achieve, you could try to allocate smaller chunks (perhaps the matrix rows?) separately or you could try to implement some kind of sparse matrix.

Comment: s.paszko and @MOehm. Please note OPs comment "this even holds for small N, say N=10".

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us?

Comment: And you do include `<stdlib.h>`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes I do, I will try to come up with a minimal example.

Comment: Size of double is 8 bytes. 8 bytes * 10^9 =~ 7629 MB. Even if you have enough RAM, if you are on Windows and if your program is compiled as a 32 bit program you won't be able to allocate more than ~2000 MB of memory. However for small values of `N` it is virtually impossible that `malloc(N*sizeof(double))` returns `NULL`. There is something you're not telling us. Show a [mcve].

Comment: It would also be good to see the definition of `N` and what its value and the value of `N * sizeof(double)` are when you allocate. There's always the possibility of a `const int` being overwritten by UB elsewhere or of a macro slip-up such as `#define N 12 - 2` without parentheses.